# How to save Image from ImageView to Android Shared Storage? I dont want my images to delete when user uninstall the app

Tags: android

I want to store my file in android Shared Storage. All the ways I have found store image in internal storage which I don't want because internal storage will be deleted when user uninstall the app.
A code would be helpful which store the image from ImageView to shared storage. I have tried reading android documentation but I don't understand what's written there.

Comment: Don't worry bro! you can store your image in internal storage if you think that the image is deleted when the application is uninstalled, you absolutely wrong thinking. if you uninstall the app when the folder in internal storage is not deleted.

Comment: The image used in your `ImageView`, where does it come from?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the table below you should use the MediaStore API for the job. Source: [Android data storage overview](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage)

[image]

Then [here's](https://github.com/coroutineDispatcher/pocket_treasure/blob/master/gallery_module/src/main/java/com/sxhardha/gallery_module/image/FullImageFragment.kt#L211) a thorough example how you can write image to file using the MediaStore API.